# How add a new column in pay pal invoice

Tags: paypal

The usual payapal invoice has some columns such as **Description, Quantity, Unit price, Amount**
How Can I add a new column like **period** or **months** and then the **amount** must be calculated by multiplying those columns like **Quantity * Unit price * period**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the customization options for the PayPal invoice does not include adding a column. However, you could treat each month as an item and use the existing logic to calculate your total.